# Kotlin coroutines with Spring JPA blocking repository

Tags: spring, kotlin, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use kotlin coroutines with "old-style" Spring JPA repository.
I create a new coroutines scope and run all JPA calls in "async".
I see that even with non reactive JDBC I improve my throughput.

But I wonder, may be exists some coroutines wrapper on Spring JPA repository?
Something created with reflection and Spring "magic"?

Answer (score 3):

First I'd like to clarify one thing to prevent a possible confusion:
If you're using Spring Data JPA, then you should know that this framework uses JDBC driver underhood, that is actually a blocking API, that means all the database calls make the calling thread block until the total result is completed and ready to be consumed.
Having that knowledge I presume you're using `suspend` functions with coroutines that run on `Dispatcher.IO` for making such calls.
This dispatcher provides you with one thread (as far as I know, it scales up to 64 threads) for each call. And that thread actually blocks while making your database call, which means coroutines and `suspend` does not make any magic in this kind of situation except for switching your blocking call to another thread (which eventually will be blocked).

Maybe you should take a look at r2dbc (reactive SQL driver) and use `CoroutineCrudRepository<T, ID>` from Spring Data instead of using standard `JpaRepostitory<T, ID>`.

`CoroutineCrudRepository<T, ID>` has all the methods with `suspend` which means you can use them for creating "truly" async API without blocking at all.

However, r2dbc may be not suitable for your use cases since it has a lot of limitations, such as mapping relations, caching and etc.

## UPDATED:

As far as I know there is no Spring-way to automatically wrap blocking calls, but you can take a look at [this library](https://github.com/konrad-kaminski/spring-kotlin-coroutine)